# Interrupt in Microblaze on AXI_GPIO (XILINX FPGA)

Tags: vhdl, interrupt, xilinx, microblaze

I study to work with FPGA (Xilinx Kintex Ultrascale).
In Vivado i create blockdesign with my module (gen_data) and Microblaze (soft processor for XILINX fpga).
Connect with Microblaze across AXI_GPIO (have 1 input and Interrupt Enable).
Gen_data is simple module (source code).
Frequency is 100 Mhz.

```
entity generate_data is
  port (
        clk : in std_logic;
        out_data : out std_logic
    );
end generate_data;

architecture Behavioral of generate_data is

begin
    process (clk)
        variable counter : integer := 0;
    begin
        if rising_edge(clk) then
            counter := counter + 1;
            if counter = 100000 then
                out_data <= '1';
                counter := 0;
            end if;                       
        end if;
    end process;
end Behavioral;
```

On Microblaze side i set interrupt but it is doesnt work.

What i need to do for work interrupt with module gen_data? Thanks.

But if i change my module (gen data) on some button then interrupt will work good.
For AXI_GPIO button is 1 input bit (similar to gen_data).

Comment: I am curious, where did you get the starting code template for this.   I would like to supply the original author with some small adjustments to the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You never set data_out to '0' so once it goes to 1, it stays there forever.  The following drives data_out to '0' and moves "count := count + 1" so that the check, counter = 100000, is against the register output rather than the newly incremented value.

```
entity generate_data is
  port (
        clk : in std_logic;
        out_data : out std_logic
    );
end generate_data;
architecture Behavioral of generate_data is
begin
    process (clk)
        variable counter : integer := 0;
    begin
        if rising_edge(clk) then
            if counter = 100000 then
                out_data <= '1';
                counter := 0;
            else
                out_data <= '0';
                counter := counter + 1
            end if;                       
        end if;
    end process;
end Behavioral;
```

Comment: Thank you. When the value of the out_data is changed then interrupt  is triggered.